# How to determine location of perl script that was symbolic linked?

Tags: perl

I've spent quite a bit of time looking for a solution on SE, but haven't come across this issue.

I have a Perl script "SCRIPT" that can be installed in different locations, but it always reads in local files (in the same dir as the script).  If the user invokes the script directly (a la ../../foo/SCRIPT) everything works as expected.   The Perl script finds the local files.

But, if the user creates a symbolic link to the Perl script (ln -s my_script ../../foo/SCRIPT), and runs the sym_link, the sym_linked Perl script is looking in the current dir for the files and not the dir local to the original location of the script.

I'm trying to figure out how to determine the path that the Perl script actually resides in.  Then I would prepend that onto the front of the files I want to read in.   Any ideas?

I've tried calling the following--

- `dirname(__FILE__)`
- abs_path()
- cwd
- dirname(abs_path($0))
- Cwd:cwd()
- Cwd::abs_rath()
- File:Basename::fileparse($0)
- Cwd:realpath($0)

but they all return the path to the link, and not the actual perl script.

Comment: `Cwd::realpath` resolves symlinks, so it should work fine. Please show the code you're having trouble with.

Comment: I simply had `print Cwd:realpath($0);` in my perl script.  I created an sym link to that script, and when I ran the sym link, it printed out the path to the sim link.

Comment: Again, `Cwd::realpath` resolves symlinks: `cd /tmp; echo 'use Cwd; print Cwd::realpath($0)' > script; ln -s script link; perl link` prints `/tmp/script`, not `/tmp/link`. Please show all of the code necessary to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Hmm.  I'm not able to reproduce it in an example.  I've moved on with the solution below.  Thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
use FindBin qw( $RealBin );
```

See [perldoc FindBin](http://perldoc.perl.org/FindBin.html). `FindBin` is a standard module and is install with Perl.

Answer (score 1):

The `readlink` builtin chases down the actual location of a symbolic link.

> **readlink EXPR**
>
> Returns the value of a symbolic link, if symbolic links are
>                  implemented.  If not, gives a fatal error.  If there is some
>                  system error, returns the undefined value and sets $! (errno).
>                  If EXPR is omitted, uses $_.

Returns `undef` if the input is not a symbolic link.

Comment: I'm not sure how this would help.  I am calling the sym_link from the command line  So it has already been called when this command (assuming it is in the perl script I called) gets called.  I think this would apply to calling the sym_link from within Perl and it would tell me if the sym_link is a sym_link, no?  (EXPR would be the file I'm opening in Perl).  Could you give me an example on how to use this?